JWT generation not correct for REST client access
I have configured my ASP.NET Core 8 web app to use JWT tokens for authentication.
This is how it is configured (still in startup.cs):
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
   options.SaveToken = true;
   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
       ValidateIssuer = true,
       ValidateAudience = true,
       ValidateLifetime = true,
       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,

       ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
       ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
   };
});

This JWT token configuration works fine when navigating to views with corresponding controllers decorated with the Authorize attribute.
However, this web app also provides a REST API, where the client (.NET Framework 4.0 WPF app) uses bearer tokens on the request header for authentication. These tokens are also generated by the application in a TokenController.
The problem I am experiencing is that the generated tokens seem incorrect. Since the response content from an API call is the HTML of the redirect page (result of a 401 response), I am concluding that the authentication failed.
This is how tokens are generated:
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginUserUser usr)
    {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();

        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(usr.username);

        if (user != null && await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, usr.password))
        {
            var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            var authClaims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            };

            foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
            {
                authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
            }

            var token = CreateToken(authClaims);
            var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken();

            user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
            var refreshTokenValidityInDays = Convert.ToInt32(Configuration["Jwt:RefreshTokenValidityInDays"]);
            user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(refreshTokenValidityInDays);

            await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            response = Ok(new
            {
                access_token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
            });
        }

        return response;
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken CreateToken(List<Claim> authClaims)
    {
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var result = new JwtSecurityToken(
          issuer: Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
          audience: Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
          claims: authClaims,
          expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440),
          signingCredentials: credentials);

        return result;
    }

For the moment, I assume there is a mismatch between the configuration and the token generation, but I could not isolate the problem or have a good debugging approach.
Update:
I have used the recommended jwt.ms website and the access token looks valid. Here is an example:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiaWdvckBpbm92YXRpdmF0ZWMuY29tIiwianRpIjoiODkzZTU4YmYtYTlmNC00Nzg3LTlmYTMtZjhhMzUxYWI4NTk3IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjpbIklubWVzIiwiQWRtaW4iLCJRdWFudGl0eSIsIlVzZXJNYW5hZ2VyIl0sImV4cCI6MTcyOTYyOTAxOCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDQzNDQiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo0NDM0NCJ9.skP2c_vhpCuUxSL_ysTCdOMe-xgmZO6OkyoSzqFUH5Y

What it is not clear to me is what should go on the issuer and audience. At the moment I used the URL of my local iss web app, but not sure if or how this interfere with my current issue,as @Mason A suggested. I verified the signature is OK.
As a sanity check, I also verified the token generated is the same as used on the client bearer authentication header
I was also able to reproduce the issue replacing the client by Postman

When debugging JWT tokens, it helps to view the generated token to see what is potentially missing. You can take the raw token and add it to [jwt.ms] (https://jwt.ms/) to see the different parts. From there, you can validate if the header, claims, or signature are invalid. If they are all invalid, you can check the issuer (iss), audience (aud), or any other validated claims in the token. The token validation step should also provide error code information regarding what is missing from the validation. I would recommend stepping through that code as well if the token decoding does not function.

For this HTML of the redirect page in response content issue, it means you are facing 401 issue, since you are using mobile device, it hard to monitor http trace. So you can test in other tools like Postman, check if it works when using the correct bearer tokens.

Because we need to make sure the restful api are working fine. In addition, I think this may be related to the timestamp, so you can also take Mason A's advice and use jwt.io to compare and see if the time in the token is too long compared to the current time.

What is the difference between a token that works and a token that does not work? can you post them to your question?. I have a blog post about Troubleshooting common JwtBearer authentication issues in ASP.NET Core https://nestenius.se/net/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/

I have updated the question based on the great received feedback. @ToreNestenius, thanks for the comment. I might be making a miss conception, but not sure: The authentication for the controllers used by the views is based on the SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method for user login, so I guess  jwt tokens might not even play a role in this case. But this mechanism is working. The problem I would say is with the client authentication via bearer jwt tokens for the REST APIs.

You have        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], in and then you use         issuer: Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
audience: Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"], in the CreateToken method, should you nout use Jwt:Audience in the CreateToken method, to be consistent?

Thanks for the heads-up, @ToreNestenius. I am unsure what to put in those values, so I defined them with the same values—the URL of my local IIS web app.

Started to write a more formal answer, so right now, what is your questions/issues?

The issuer should be set to a string, that represents who created/issued the token. In your case, when you create them yourself, you can call it "MyClientApplication" or what ever.
The audience in the token typically repsents who is the accesstoken created for, it could be "MyBackendAPI", or "MyPaymentAPI" or "MyOrderAPI".
The JwtBearer can use the issuer to check if the creator of the token is what I expect and the audience allows the API to check if the API is meant for me.
Compare it to the hotel, the door wants to ensure the key card was created(issued) by my hotel and the cards audience is the door lock to my room. The audience could also be the "guest rooms" and not the conference rooms/area.


OK, I have set for now my issuer to "MyClientApp" and audience to "MyBackendAPI", but unfortunately this has not changed anything. I also set the ValidateAudience and ValidateIssuer to false on startup.cs. But I am still having 401 (or redirect to login page more specifically). Any thoughts?

Via Postman the behavior is the same.

The classic misstake when doing this is if you both have the API and the client in the same service, if you are redirected, then that means the Cookie Handler sees that the request have a cookie, and take charge. Not allowing JWT-bearer to see it. You can't mix the authorization cookie and JWT-tokens.

If I understand correctly, would separating the "API controllers" and the "View controllers" into separate web applications solve my problem? Each would have a different authentication mechanism...

My recomendations to get started is to always separate the authorization server, the client and the API, then you can get it working and then combine them later, if needed, when you know how it works and behaves. Separations of concerns is the key here, ensuring that you can reason about the system behavior. Both the Cookie and JwtBearer handler authenticate the user and creates the ClaimsPrincipal object. In your case, both JwtBearer and the Cookie handler tries to authenticate the user, but probaly only the cookie handler is active when the current request is authenticated.

Thank you for the advice. I now decorate the API controllers with the following authorize attribute: [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]. This way, they can coexist for the moment in the same app.
